# Deluge refuses non-localhost connections (remote connections allowed)

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I have checked other questions before posting this one, I cannot find a duplicate of my issue. I have a kubuntu box which I have `deluge` and `deluged` installed on. `Deluged` is set up and is working locally, however despite setting remote connections to be allowed, it is not letting in remote connections. I should say my linux knowledge is a little limited.

Here are the relevant options in my deluge `core.conf`

```
{
 ...
 "allow_remote": true,
 ...
 "daemon_port": 58846,
 ...
}
```

I have run netstat and it's listening ip is 0.0.0.0

```
$ netstat -npl | grep 58846
Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address   Foreign Address     State   PID/Program name
tcp     0       0       0.0.0.0:58846   0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN  2261/python3
```

And the process seems to be attached to deluged

```
$ ps -p 2261
PID         TTY     TIME CMD
2261        ?       00:03:00 deluged
```

I've even added the port to iptables just in case

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2194 packets, 432K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  458 52411 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:58846
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, any advice would be greatly received.

Comment: If deluged isn't on a system using a public IP address, then the home router might need specific settings.

Comment: It wasn't using a public IP address, but now it is and it's still not connecting. I used to have it running on a windows box which worked both as a public ip and private one.